# UITableView Custom Header Section White line

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I m trying to create a custom `UITableView` with `png` borders. The problem I m facing is that in the bottom of the **Header Section Cell**, there is an **extra white line**, check the screenshots:

[image]
[image]

I tried to remove the separator style, but it's not working:

```
_tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm newbie, but maybe this can help you.

If it is a header cell, you can add the content of that cell to a groupcell. That was the only solution for me to hide that line. You could see TimeUntilAlarm on github, and focus to the .mm file in prefs and *prefs.plist in resources.

Hope this help you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I m not looking for a groupCell approach, actually I tried it but I experienced the same problem. What I think is that there is always a separator between a `Header Section` and `cells`